# Getting error while Setting aws localStack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, localstack

I am getting error while setting up aws-localstack can anyone help?
Getting error for importing a lot of entrypoint after running "docker-compose up" below are few of them.

```
    localstack_main | [22] [INFO] Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)
    localstack_main | INFO:hypercorn.error: Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)
    localstack_main | INFO:bootstrap.py: Execution of "start_runtime_components" took 1814.49ms 
    localstack_main | ERROR:plugin.manager: error importing entrypoint EntryPoint(name='amplify:pro', value='localstack_ext.services.providers:amplify', group='localstack.aws.provider'): No module named 'localstack_ext.services.providers'
    localstack_main | DEBUG:stevedore.extension: found extension EntryPoint(name='apigateway:pro', value='localstack_ext.services.providers:apigateway', group='localstack.aws.provider')
    localstack_main | ERROR:plugin.manager: error importing entrypoint EntryPoint(name='apigateway:pro', value='localstack_ext.services.providers:apigateway', group='localstack.aws.provider'): No module named 'localstack_ext.services.providers'
    localstack_main | DEBUG:stevedore.extension: found extension EntryPoint(name='appconfig:pro', value='localstack_ext.services.providers:appconfig', group='localstack.aws.provider')
    localstack_main | ERROR:plugin.manager: error importing entrypoint EntryPoint(name='appconfig:pro', value='localstack_ext.services.providers:appconfig', group='localstack.aws.provider'): No module named 'localstack_ext.services.providers'
    localstack_main | DEBUG:stevedore.extension: found extension EntryPoint(name='application-autoscaling:pro', value='localstack_ext.services.providers:application_autoscaling', group='localstack.aws.provider')
```

Many more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Piyush Sahay I have the same problem, did you find a fix on your setup?